# Failed to lookup view "login.ejs"

Tags: node.js, render, ejs

I have follow structure in a project:

```
app
- views
- controllers
- middlewares
- routes
- models
- passport
server.js
public - client part
```

I use `ejs` for output my views `server.js`:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'views'));
```

In controllers I do the render page login:

```
loginPage(req, res) {
    res.render('login.ejs', {});
},
```

and i get an error:

```
Failed to lookup view "login.ejs" in views directory "D:\MyRepositories\TestMEAN\views"
```

If I will write using absolute path I won't get any the errors:

```
loginPage(req, res) {
    res.render('../app/views/login.ejs', {});
},
```

Versions of npm and node is next:

```
npm: 5.4.2  
node: 8.7.0
```

I want to understand why non-absolute path doesn't work. I looked for many different articles like scotch, medium and also saw a lot of answers at stackoverflow and try to repeat as writting in it but the error output. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATED:
server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import passport from 'passport';
import fs from 'fs';
import flash from 'connect-flash';
import session from 'express-session';
import cors from 'cors';
import routes from './app/routes';
import initPassport from './app/passport/passport-init';
import path from 'path';
import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
const app = express();

mongoose.connect(`${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_NAME}`);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '/favicon.png')));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'views'));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'passport',
        resave: false,
        saveUnitialized: false
    })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(flash());

app.use(cors());

app.use('/', routes);

initPassport(passport);

const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port);

export default app;
```

authController:

```
import passport from 'passport';

export default {

    loginPage(req, res) {
        res.render('../app/views/login.ejs', {});
    },

    login(req, res) {
        passport.authenticate('login', { failureFlash: true }, (err, userData) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.name === 'Incorrect Credentials Error') {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        message: 'Incorrect Credentials Error'
                    });
                }

                return res.status(400).json({
                    messages: 'Could not process the form.'
                });
            }

            if (userData) {
                return res.status(200).redirect('/app');
            } else {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: req.flash('loginMessage')[0],
                })
            }

        })(req, res);
    },

    signUpPage(req, res) {
        res.render('../app/views/signup.ejs', {});
    },

    signUp(req, res) {
        passport.authenticate('signup', { failureFlash: true }, err => {

            if (err) {
                if (err.name === 'Incorrect Credentials Error') {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        message: 'Incorrect Credentials Error'
                    });
                }

                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: 'Could not process the form.'
                });
            }

            return res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Sign up is successfully'
            });

    })(req, res);
    },

    mainPage(req, res) {
        res.render('../app/views/app.ejs', {});
    }
}
```

authRoute:

```
import express from 'express';
import authController from '../controllers/authController';
const router = express();

router.get('/login', authController.loginPage);
router.post('/login', authController.login);
router.get('/signup', authController.signUpPage);
router.post('/signup', authController.signUp);
router.get('/app', authController.mainPage);

export default router;
```

Comment: Technically a path with a `../` isn't absolute, it's still relative, but I get what you're saying. Does `res.render('login', {})` work? I believe you're supposed to omit the extension when you've specified the view engine and you're letting the `render()` method locate the template file.

Comment: I write `login` instead of `login.ejs` but the error is outputting. If I understood you correctly I should remove this line: `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');` ? P.S. I'm a beginner in English.

Comment: that is because controllers is not the main file, can you show me what you do in controllers? do you export ?

Comment: I updated my question and added link on repository.

Comment: I figured it out a solution. I removed `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')` from `server.js` and add relative path to files.